# Loop OBJECT and obtain both key and value

Tags: php, arrays, object, loops

Ok, here we go. I hope I explain this correctly.

I have an object that i'd like to loop through to obtain both the key and value. Here is an example of the object I'm receiving. Thanks in advance for any help or ideas.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 93
            [RecordGUID] => 
            [txtEmplid] => 0134754
            [txtFname] => 
            [txtLname] => 
            [txtMname] => 
            [txtEmail] => 
            [txtSecEmail] => 
            [txtPhoneNo] => 4046565454
            [drpMajor] => 
            [drpStatus] => 
            [regmain] => 
            [chkDental] => 0
            [chkDO] => 
            [chkMD] => 
            [chkMDPHD] => 
            [chkNursin] => 
            [chkOPT] => 
            [chkPA] => 
            [chkPH] => 
            [chkPharm] => 
            [chkPOD] => 
            [chkPostBac] => 
            [chkVet] => 
        )

)
```

I basically need to loop through the above info getting both the key and value. For example:

```
id=93
RecordGUID=
txtEmplid=0134754
```

and so on.

Again, thanks in advance for any answers.

UPDATE for DBF
Here is what I get when I use your code snippt:

```
int(0)
object(stdClass)#27 (24) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "93"
  ["RecordGUID"]=>
  NULL
  ["txtEmplid"]=>
  string(7) "0134754"
  ["txtFname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["txtLname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["txtMname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["txtEmail"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["txtSecEmail"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["txtPhoneNo"]=>
  string(10) "4045506561"
  ["drpMajor"]=>
  NULL
  ["drpStatus"]=>
  NULL
  ["regmain"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkDental"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["chkDO"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkMD"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkMDPHD"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkNursin"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkOPT"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkPA"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkPH"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkPharm"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkPOD"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkPostBac"]=>
  NULL
  ["chkVet"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok, can you post the code where you use your foreach loop? In other words, where you say `foreach($object as $key=>$value)` do `foreach($object[0] as $key=>$value)` instead. Essentially, you are currently looping the Array object, not the Object at index 0.

Comment: foreach($regs as $key=>$value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
}

Comment: What @ParahatMelayev wrote is what you need, only if you know the exact index of the object you want to iterate through, you can use just one foreach, if not, and you have multiple objects in your array, just double fore aches

Comment: k, so use `foreach($regs[0] as $key=>$value)`

Comment: Now, it's coming back like this: 
string(9) "txtEmplid"
string(7) "0134754"
string(8) "txtFname"
string(0) ""

Answer (score 32, accepted):

use `get_object_vars ( object $object )`

```
$vars = get_object_vars ( $object );
foreach($vars as $key=>$value) {
  var_dump($key);
  var_dump($value);
}
```

or just iterate the object itself

```
foreach($object as $key=>$value) {
  var_dump($key);
  var_dump($value);
}
```

-- edit 2

Here you'll have the keys and values in one line

```
$string = "";
foreach($regs as $object) {
  foreach($object as $key=>$value) {
    $string += "{$key}={$value} ";
  }
}
echo $string;
```

if this is not what you need, I'm clueless ..

Comment: I used your second code sample and got basically the same thing I have now. I can't echo out just the $key values or the $value values like I needed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong without code? :D Edit your post with the current loop/foreach structure you are using now, and let's take a look from there

Comment: this didn't work var_dump($key, $value); but this did echo $key and echo $value which was exactly what I was looking for. THANK YOU.

Comment: Now, I can go to bed happy. :-)

Comment: Haha, cheers ;) fyi, `var_dump` means "variable dump", which is a debugging method to see what kind of value it has, what type it is, etc. `echo` on the other hand "displays" the value on the parser/html, or very plain said, in the browser :P

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through object properties with `foreach`

```
foreach($array as $key => $object)
    foreach($object as $property => $value)
        echo "{$property} : $value" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: See the php manual [page for foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). It specifies that foreach works on object properties and that there is a $key=>$value syntax.